# Constrained randomization of column order in a data.frame

Tags: r, random, dataframe

I am trying to duplicate each column from data frame and move it to a randomly located point within 1-3 columns and do it for each column in the data frame. I want columns to move AT LEAST one space to the left or right. Of course `sample(data)` reorders columns randomly, but my attempts to put it in a loop are embarrassingly bad (I admit I skipped majority of linear algebra classes, damn...). Below is an example data:

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection(
"-515.5718  94.33423 939.6324 -502.9918 -75.14629 946.6926
-515.2283  96.10239 939.5687 -503.1425 -73.39015 946.6360
-515.0044  97.68119 939.4177 -503.4021 -71.79252 946.6909
-514.7430  99.59141 939.3976 -503.6645 -70.08514 946.6887
-514.4449 101.08511 939.2342 -503.9207 -68.48133 946.7183
-514.2769 102.29453 939.0013 -504.2665 -67.04509 946.7809
-513.9294 104.02753 938.9436 -504.4703 -65.34361 946.7899
-513.5900 105.49624 938.7684 -504.7405 -63.75965 946.7991"
),header=F,as.is=T)
sample(dat)#random columns position
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this brute-force but plenty-fast solution?

It tries out different permutations of the columns until it finds one in which each column is moved at least 1, and not more than 3 columns to left or right. When it finds such a permutation, the test in the final line of the `while()` call evaluates to `FALSE`, terminating the loop and leaving the variable `x` containing the acceptable permutation.

```
n <- ncol(dat)
while({x <- sample(n)   # Proposed new column positions
       y <- seq_len(n)  # Original column positions
       max(abs(x - y)) > 3 | min(abs(x - y)) == 0
       }) NULL
dat[x]
```

Comment: I can't tell for sure whether you want to also ensure that every column is moved **at least** one space to left or right. If that's the case, though, extending this code to cover the added condition should be easy enough ;)

Comment: Yes, I want them to move AT LEAST one space to the left or right - added to the description.

Comment: @GeekOnAcid -- Good. I've edited it to test both conditions, and keep looping until it finds a permutation fitting both criteria.

Comment: Thank you, it's a great small loop. Just one question,if you don't mind - how would you modify this loop to move 2 consecutive columns instead of 1 using the same pattern?

Comment: @GeekOnAcid -- Could you show me what you mean, using the column indices? For example, running the code above I just got this permuation: `2 1 4 3 6 5`. Do you want all pairs (`list(c(1,2), c(3,4), c(5,6))`) to move around as blocks? Do you just want to move one randomly determined pair, swapping it's position with another pair?  If you list a few examples of the kinds of permutations you're after, I'll have a better chance of helping.  Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what you said. To be even more specific - I want THREE sets of columns `(list(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), c(7,8,9), etc...))` to move around as blocks, in the data frame of 90 columns. So each set of 3 columns will swap places with any other set of 3 columns, but using the limits you defined in the function above.

Comment: @GeekOnAcid -- Cool. I've got to be working on other projects all day here, but will give this a shot if you haven't already figured it out, in 12 hours or so.  Cheers.

Comment: @GeekOnAcid -- I've got something that works for the problem as I understand it. I will post it later today as a second answer when I get a chance to clean it up a bit.

Comment: @GeekOnAcid -- OK, I've posted a solution for moving 3 blocks of 3 columns between 1 and 2 blocks to the left or right in a 90 column data.frame.  Since I can't see the exact data/problem you are working on, it likely won't fit your circumstance exactly, but should give you some ideas of how to proceed.  Let me know how it works for you. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I should probably wait to post this until I have time to comment it up, and discuss some of the ambiguities in the problem as currently specified in the comments above.  But since I won't be able to do that, possibly for a while, I thought I'd give you code for a solution that you can examine yourself.

```
# Create a function that generates acceptable permutations of the data
getPermutation <- function(blockSize,     # number of columns/block
                           nBlock,        # number of blocks of data
                           fromBlocks) {  # indices of blocks to be moved
    X <- unique(as.vector(outer(fromBlocks, c(-2,-1,1,2), "+")))
    # To remove nonsensical indices like 0 or -1
    X <- X[X %in% seq.int(nBlock)]  

    while({toBlocks <- sample(X, size = length(fromBlocks))  
           max(abs(toBlocks - fromBlocks)) > 2 | min(abs(toBlocks - fromBlocks)) < 1
           }) NULL
    A <- seq.int(nBlock)
    A[toBlocks] <- fromBlocks
    A[fromBlocks] <- toBlocks

    blockColIndices <- 
        lapply(seq.int(nBlock) - 1,
               function(X) {
                   seq(from = X * blockSize + 1, 
                       by = 1, 
                       length.out = blockSize)
               })    
    unlist(blockColIndices[A])
}

# Create an example dataset, a 90 column data.frame
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(seq.int(90*4), ncol=90))

# Call the function for a data frame with 30 3-column blocks
# within which you want to move blocks 2, 14, and 14.
index <- getPermutation(3, 30, c(2, 14, 15))
newdat <- dat[index]
```